# zend echo message from controller to view

Tags: php, forms, validation, zend-framework, echo

I try to echo a message from controller to view, and it doesn't even display it.

It validates all the emails that the user had enter, send those are valid and display those are not valid.

But it's not displaying those are not valid in the view when submit is press, but it does send those a valid.

here's a bit of my code:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $this->url(array(), 'inviteByEmail'); ?>">
            <table><tr>
                <td>Email Addresses:* <span class="right small_font" style="margin-right:25px;">* Each email address must be separated by a comma ( , )</span></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><input class="input_long" type="text" name="emails" /></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><br/>Personalize your message:</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><textarea cols="49" rows="7" name="personal_message"  id="share-text" style="margin-bottom:8px;" placeholder="Download Ad-Aware and help me get PRO version" ></textarea></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td rowspan="3" valign="top">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn_submit_step3" id="btn_friends" value="share_friends" /><br/>
                </td>
            </tr></table>
        </form> <?php echo $this->error; ?>
```

controller:

```
public function inviteByEmailAction()
{
    $emails = $this->getRequest()->getParam('emails');
    $personal_message = $this->getRequest()->getParam('personal_message');

    $emails = explode(",", $emails);

    foreach ($emails as $email)
    {
        $email = trim($email);
        $validator = new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress();

        // Validate emails that exists in Database
        $valiadtor_email_in_dbUsers = new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists (
            array (
                'table' => 'users',
                'field' => 'email'
            )
        );

        $valiadtor_email_in_dbReferrals = new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists (
            array (
                'table' => 'referrals',
                'field' => 'email'
            )
        );

        if ($validator->isValid($email)) 
        {
            if ($valiadtor_email_in_dbUsers->isValid($email))
            {
                if ($valiadtor_email_in_dbReferrals->isValid($email))
                {
                    if ($this->_helper->model('EmailInvites')->noRowByFields(array('email' => $email, 'referred_by_user_id' => $this->_helper->user()->id)))
                    {
                        $email_invite = $this->_helper->model('EmailInvites')->createRow();  
                        $email_invite->email = $email;
                        $email_invite->personal_message = $personal_message;
                        $email_invite->referred_by_user_id = $this->_helper->user()->id;
                        $email_invite->save();

                        $this->_helper->user()->sendInviteEmail($email, $personal_message);
                    }
                } else {
                    echo $email . " already exists";
                                            $this->view->error = $email . " already exists";
                }
            }else {
                    echo $email . " already exists";
                                            $this->view->error = $email . " already exists";
                }
        }
    }
    $this->getHelper('redirector')->gotoRoute(array(), 'invite');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The echo is in the inviteByEmailAction(). That means, it will display in the inviteByEmail.phtml view. However, after the echo, you are redirecting to inviteAction at this line.

```
  $this->getHelper('redirector')->gotoRoute(array(), 'invite');
```

That is why you do not see the echo displayed.

If you do not want the redirect to happen if there is error, you need to add a return statement after the echo like:

```
   } else {
                echo $email . " already exists";
                $this->view->error = $email . " already exists";
                 return;
            }
        }else {
                echo $email . " already exists";
                $this->view->error = $email . " already exists";
                return;
            }
```

If you want to redirect, and also display the error message, you can use the [Flashmessenger](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.flashmessenger) helper before redirecting.

Comment: Thanks, I will try out the flashmessager, the redirect path is actually redirecting to the same page. and the return give me a error.